# Is there an Out-of-the-Box way to sum all Opportunity Products related to an Opportunity?

Tags: formula, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, roll-up-summary

I am trying to sum the 'Total Price' of related Opportunity Products for a given Opportunity. I would like to then display that value on the Opportunity Page Layout. Is there an Out-of-the-Box way to do this?

For example: I have 2 Products related to an Opportunity. I would like to take the Quantity * Sales Price of each, add them, and display that value on the Opportunity with a field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're looking for is a [Rollup Summary Field](https://www.google.com/search?q=rollup+summary+field&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which works with Master-Detail relationships.

The most notable pair of (standard) objects you can't use this for is making a rollup on `Account` that summarizes related `Contact`s.

The key here is making a formula field on `OpportunityLineItem` to do the qty * price step for you. The rollup field would then just sum that formula field.

Formula fields can be rolled up as long as they only use data on their defined object (i.e. as long as they're not cross-object formulas like `PricebookEntry.Product.Some_Custom_Field__c` or depend, directly or indirectly, on a cross-object formula).

Answer (score 1):

The standard field on the Opportunity object called 'Amount' is designed for this.